# Zynga Scroller - detect click on cell

Tags: javascript, html

I can't find any examples on [the github site](http://zynga.github.com/scroller/) or when googling for how to detect click-events for the Zynga Scroller.

For example, starting off with the [Pull-to-refresh](http://zynga.github.com/scroller/demo/dom-list.html) demo it contains this code:

```
if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
    container.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
        scroller.doTouchStart(e.touches, e.timeStamp);
        e.preventDefault(); // Problem !!! 
}, false);
```

Since we are always preventing Default, I can never click a row in the scrollable list. If I remove that line, I can click but then scrolling does not work.

Is there any other way to detect the click?

(On a computer it works, but not on smartphone with ontouchstart event, (iPhone 4s))

Answer (score 1):

This because scrollerObject prevent users Actions, depending on used Zynga scroller plugin you use for example on EazyScroller.js, search for this code **`that.scroller.doTouchStart(e.touches, e.timeStamp)`** and delete the <strike>e.preventDefault()</strike> on the next line :

> that.scroller.doTouchStart(e.touches, e.timeStamp);
>   //e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 1):

Check for prevent  `e.preventDefault();` on `touchstart`.

Comment that and add `e.preventDefault();` to `touchmove` function's end.

That did the trick for me.